# MySQL Editing a Specific Column

Tags: php, mysql

Ok. So here's what I want to do.

I would like to make it so that a piece of code, grabs the contents form the variable

```
$_SESSION['user']
```

and find the row in the MySQL table the contains that variable.

Then I want it to edit a row that already has information in it by grabbing information from another variable such as

```
$_POST['country']
```

I have no idea how to do this. Is there a simple way.

The MySQL info is:

```
 host: 'localhost'
 user: 'root'
 pass: ''
   db: 'database'
table: 'accounts'
```

Comment: So, you prefer wasting our time, because you're too lazy to study?

Comment: @SteppingHat, this might be easier for you but not for the SO community. Have you tried to research on Google? You'll find many-many basic tutorials explaining how to read and write to MySQL using a PHP script. Try reading on SELECT and UPDATE queries in MySQL, those are the only stuff you will need

Comment: @SteppingHat owning a book is not enough, you also need to read it. I say you're off to a good start here...And please, for the future, don't think at SO as your personal wikipedia or code provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE accounts SET country='%s' WHERE user_id='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['country']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user'])
));
```

Just replace the field/table with their respective names.

The actual SQL you're learning here is:

```
UPDATE table SET field='value', field2='value2', ... WHERE field3='value3', ...
```

Make sure to always sanitize the input as done with mysql_real_escape_string; Not doing this leaves a hole in your system which is very easy to exploit - and at worst costs you your database to be dropped, sensitive data to be exposed or a hacker to succesfully authorize himself as another user.

And if you havn't connected to the database, you do this (before running the query):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("database");
```